# clang compilation error with template function

Tags: c++, c++11, clang

I'm compiling some code (which I wrote and compiled fine with the microsoft
toolchain) with clang. Here is some piece of code for which I do not understand the error:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

template <int N>
auto foo(int index, std::bitset<N> & already_given)->int
{
        return 0;
}


auto bar()->void
{
        auto const n = 10;

        auto baz = std::bitset<n>{};
        for (auto i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                std::cout << foo(i, baz)
                          << std::endl;
        }
}
```

gives me the error `no matching function to call to 'foo'`.
What is the source of this error?

Comment: Microsoft toolchain or clang (using the MS compiler)? What exactly please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::bitset` is a class template that takes its argument as a `std::size_t`:

```c++
template< std::size_t N >
class bitset;
```

When doing `auto baz = std::bitset<n>{};`, `n` is implicitly-convertible to `std::size_t`, but during template argument deduction the types must match exactly [temp.deduct.type]/p17:

> If, in the declaration of a function template with a non-type *template-parameter*, the non-type *template-parameter* is used in an expression in the function parameter-list and, if the corresponding *template-argument* is deduced, the *template-argument* type shall match the type of the *template-parameter* exactly, except that a *template-argument* deduced from an array bound may be of any integral type.

The non-type template parameter `int N` deduces the argument from an integer, which doesn't match the type of the bitset, so you have a deduction failure.

To fix this, you need to change your parameter to match the type:

```c++
template <std::size_t N>
auto foo(int index, std::bitset<N>& already_given) -> int;
```

Answer (score 1):

`bitset<N>` is a class template declared as follows [template.bitset]:

```
namespace std {
  template <size_t N> class bitset;
}
```

Its non-type template parameter is of the type `size_t`, not `int`, [support.types]/p6:

> The type `size_t` is an implementation-defined unsigned integer type that is large enough to contain the size in bytes of any object.

Therefore, you should rewrite your function template as follows:

```
#include <cstddef> // size_t

template <std::size_t N>
//        ~~~~~~~~~~^
auto foo(int index, std::bitset<N> & already_given)->int
{
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Need an extra quote about why this mismatch of types causes deduction to fail ([temp.deduct.type]/p17).